# XMLHttpRequest cannot load because response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post

I have been trying to make a post request with custom headers to a server. However I keep getting the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.xxx.com:8080/upload. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I read up on the answers on the internet but I could not find a solution. The code is being hosted on localhost:8000

Here's the code:

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
    alert("click");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        headers: { 'userID': '123456789', 'title':'Website', 'type':'fill_in'},
        url :"http://api.xxx.com:8080/upload",
        contentType: 'text-plain',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success',data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('status', xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

the server is running cherrypy, heres the relevant code:

```
cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"] = "userID, title, type"
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115825/cors-wcf-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control/41115880#41115880

Comment: @Leopard - what makes you think this has anything to do with WCF, or IIS at all?

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't mention it for WCF or IIS it mentioned because error is same and resolution will be same but different in syntax of course.

Comment: @Leopard - I see that, I just thought you knew something more about the OP's environment than they let on :p

Comment: @IDK - in your research, did you read about CORS preflight for POST requests with custom headers. 1 - the browser sends an OPTIONS request, the server needs to reply less generically to an OPTIONS preflight request for CORS to be granted

Comment: @JaromandaX I did see the preflight stuff, but i must have missed something, please could you explain what you mean by less generically?

Comment: Well, you'll need `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response (not `Access-Control-Request-Headers` ) - and there are circumstances where `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is unacceptable response, the response must have the requesting origin host in the response (I'm not 100% sure when that applies off the top of my head) - a quick search, and you should be OK with `*` as long as you aren't making requests with credentials